# Bounties for Safehold series questions!

Tags: discussion, contest

Since I'm bored, and want to re-read [*Safehold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safehold), and want an excuse:

From now till January 1, 2016, any questions about David Weber's *Safehold* series are entered into a drawing to be bountied (and a bounty gets you extra question upvotes, usually). I will post at least one bounty, but if several great questions are asked, maybe more.

Extra bonus: I will match ANY bounty up to 100 rep points posted by @Richard on top of any bounties I would have posted otherwise on Safehold questions.

Comment: It's on like Donkey Kong!

Comment: If something needs bountying, just point me at it :-)

Comment: @Richard - `select * from posts where user=976`